# Authorize to Microsoft Azure app with Oauth and PHP

Tags: php, azure, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to login to my app on Microsoft Azure. But I can't get a code to access the token registration. My goal is to login with a php app and get access to the Business Central API.

This is the code I'm using to authorize, but I don't get any answer back. The var_dump contains NULL. The tenant, client_id and client_secret I'm using are valid.

```
$url = "https://login.windows.net/TENANT/oauth2/authorize";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array(
   "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&response_type=code&state=12345&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **url encode** your header data **values**. use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

if you still get an error after url encoding your header values,
try `grant_type=client_credentials` instead of `grant_type=authorization_code`.

**Example** : $data = "grant_type=" + urlencode('client_credentials') + "&client_id=" + urlencode('your_client_id') + "&client_secret=" + urlencode('your_client_secret') + "&scope=" + urlencode('https://graph.microsoft.com/.default');